# Sticky navigation with horizontal layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sticky

I've been searching around and have yet to find a solution to this. I have a horizontal page set up with a fixed navigation. However, I want the navigation to have a sticky effect exactly like [this](http://stickyjs.com/), but instead of sticking when scrolling from the top (which the site I'm working on doesn't scroll up and down at all), I'd like it to stick after a percentage scroll from the left. Does anyone know of some sort of solution or work-around with an existing jquery plugin?

Here's the [site](http://usnakedthefilm.com/site/): 
If you scroll to the left from where it loads, there's a little news section, but I want the navigation to stay in an absolute position on the landing portion until you scroll right from there so as not to interfere with the news text.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdRmA/2/):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(window).height()+101) {
    $('#hello').css({'position':'fixed','top':'0px'});
}
else{
    $('#hello').css({'position':'relative'});
}
});
```

I have included `$(window).height()` in *if(condition)* inorder to give same output when the browser window height changes.

Comment: I used this and edited it so instead of detecting window height, once it passed a div it would enable. Thanks so much! Huge help in getting this finally working!!